# GWT Editor Set Path Programmatically

Tags: gwt, path, annotations, editor

If you are defining an Editor in GWT using the UiBinder, then you can specify the path to a property value using the @Path annotation.

If you are defining an Editor without using the UiBinder (i.e programmatically), how can you specify the path to an editable attribute without using the annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You can `use the same @Path annotation on the declared fields`.

`It is not bound to UiBinder.`

You can bind properties to fields in 2 ways -

1) Declare the field with the same name as the property.

2) @Path annotation, in case, if the field and the property are declared with different names.

If you don't want to bind any property to the field, declare that field with @Ignore annotation.

These annotations are all used by Editor Framework's Code generator to generate some supporting java classes.

So, `At Runtime` you can not change the `Path of the editors programmatically`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your UI programmatically, you can still use `@Path` (or just name the field to match the property) on a field in your widget class. Not using UiBinder doesn't mean you can't use the Editor Framework.

That said, paths cannot be defined programmatically, no matter how you build the ui. The Editor Driver generating code requires that it can see which properties will be used so it only generates the necessary code to wire properties into editors.

Editor and UiBinder are totally distinct features - it just so happens that both can wire into fields in your class. UiBinder doesn't care about `@Path` annotations any more than Editors care about `@UiField`